# Client Missing Intents Error (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I've been working on a discord bot I made for about a year, although I stopped for a bit a couple months ago. Anyway, I was getting back into it, and last night a made a "-say (something)" command for my bot. It was working out just fine, but today, I check up on the bot again, and I start getting an error about how I didn't state valid intents, but this is my code (for the client intents).

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"]});
```

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong, I'd be super grateful if you could let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any intents in your code.

Comment: Which ones should I add? https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS

Comment: Who am I to decide what intents you want for *your* bot?

Comment: Yeah I know but generally which would be useful? My bot mostly just responds to messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits , Partials } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    ],
     partials: [Partials.Message, Partials.Channel, Partials.Reaction]
)}
```

you need to use this if you are on v14

Comment: I just tried what you sent, but it didn't work. I'm also not getting any errors which is annoying. And I'm pretty sure the entire bot isn't working because I set a status for the bot, but that isn't showing up on discord either.

Comment: nvm its working now. it just had to do with the version and some stuff like that. its fine now! tahnks